# defaultIndex property doesn't change after re-render cycle in "React Native Searchable Dropdown"

Tags: javascript, react-native

I'm trying to use Searchable-Dropdown in a pretty simple component like that:

```
import React from 'react';
import {View} from 'react-native';
import SearchableDropdown from 'react-native-searchable-dropdown';

const DropDownList = props => {

return (

<SearchableDropdown
onItemSelect={(item) => {
props.onChoosingItem(item);
}}
defaultIndex = {props.defaultIndex}
containerStyle={styles.containerDDL}
itemStyle={{...styles.itemDDL,...props.itemStyle}}
itemTextStyle={{...styles.itemDDLText, ...props.textStyle}}
itemsContainerStyle={styles.itemContainerDDL}
items={props.ddlItems}
resetValue={false}
textInputStyle={{...styles.ddlTextInput,...props.textInputStyle}}
onTextChange = { text => console.log(text)}
listProps={
{
nestedScrollEnabled: true,
}
}
/>

);
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
*<"Styles definitions">*
}
});

export default DropDownList;
```

But for some reason, **props.defaultIndex** property is read, and assigned to the **defaultIndex** property of the react-native-searchable-dropdown itself very only first render cycle. After "DropDownList" 's rendered first time, SearchableDropdown doesn't try to read this value though the whole component ("DropDownList") is rendered every time when the props change. Is it the react-native-searchable-dropdown issue, or I use it incorrectly?

Answer (score 0):

I see the reason, defaultIndex property is set on componentDidMount call only (inside react-native-searchable-dropdown component),as result defaultIndex won't be changed after first time, when the component has been mounted